# I dont understand why my makefile is relinking

Tags: makefile

I have the following files:

- Makefile
- libft.h
- ft_atoi.c
- ft_itoa.c
- ...

And the following Makefile:

```make
SRC_FILES:=$(wildcard *.c)

NAME=libft.a

LIBSO=libft.so

CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -Werror -g

OBJ_DIR=obj/

HDR_NAME=libft.h

SRC_NAMES=${SRC_FILES:.c=.o}

SRC_NAMES_O=$(addprefix $(OBJ_DIR), $(SRC_NAMES))

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR) $(SRC_NAMES)
    ar -rc $@ $(SRC_NAMES_O)
    ranlib $@

$(OBJ_DIR):
    mkdir $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(OBJ_DIR)$@ 

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)

sclean: clean
    rm -rf $(NAME) $(LIBSO)

fclean: clean
    rm -f $(NAME)

re: fclean all

so:
    $(CC) -nostartfiles -fPIC $(CFLAGS) $(SRC_FILES) $(BONUS_FILES)
    gcc -nostartfiles -shared -o libft.so $(SRC_FILES) $(BONUS_FILES)

.PHONY: all bonus clean sclean fclean re so
```

But it is relinking. What did I do Wrong? I feel like it should run but it keeps recompiling everything each time I run `make`.

Comment: Relinking or recompiling?  You said one then the other.  Perhaps both?

Answer (score 1):

By code-review-only, I suspect that the culprit is the following line:

```make
$(NAME): $(OBJ_DIR) $(SRC_NAMES)
    ar -rc $@ $(SRC_NAMES_O)
    ranlib $@
```

Namely, `$(OBJ_DIR)` is a normal prerequisite of `$(NAME)`, so each time a file (or subdirectory) in the `obj/` directory is created, renamed, or deleted, the timestamp of `obj` changes, and thereby triggers a rebuild of the `make all` target.

To avoid this, you may want to replace this target with:

```make
$(NAME): $(SRC_NAMES) | $(OBJ_DIR)
    ar -rc $@ $(SRC_NAMES_O)
    ranlib $@
```

The underlying concept of GNU Make is called [*order-only prerequisite*](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-prerequisites_002c-order_002donly):

> Occasionally (…) you have a situation where you want to impose a specific ordering on the rules to be invoked *without* forcing the target to be updated if one of those rules is executed. In that case, you want to define *order-only* prerequisites. Order-only prerequisites can be specified by placing a pipe symbol (|) in the prerequisites list: any prerequisites to the left of the pipe symbol are normal; any prerequisites to the right are order-only:
>
> ```
> targets : normal-prerequisites | order-only-prerequisites
> ```
>
> The normal prerequisites section may of course be empty. (…)

Comment: _so each time a file matching path obj/* is modified_ is not quite right.  By declaring a prerequisite on a directory `obj`, your target will rebuild whenever the modification time of the directory itself changes.  A directory's modification time changes whenever a file (or subdirectory) in that directory is _created_, _renamed_, or _deleted_.  It doesn't change when a file is _modified_ (unless the editor you're using performs some kind of rename operation during save).  But yes, you (almost) never want to list a directory as a normal prerequisite of a target.